# can't run geth command on windows10

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I install GETH on Windows10 but when I execute the command

> geth version

it will get an error "geth' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I now this is a basic question I try previously its working fine. and also geth is installed correctly when I execute the geth command in the geth folder its working fine. when I check the version or enter different command for creating private blockchain for eg:geth --datadir =./mydir init genesis.json it will get an error

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something to do with your environmental variables and dependencies.

Firstly ensure that you have installed all dependencies correctly. Follow the installation steps here 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows

This will ensure that all env paths are set correctly and that geth will be configured into your system variables.

Hope this helps! feel free to message me if you have anymore trouble

Comment: I follow this installation steps still I got this error

Comment: that's odd there are two things you can try, one is running geth from the bin folder it has been installed etc from 'C:/Users/usr/bin' and ./geth version. Could you also send some screenshots of all the steps you are taking, it would allow me to see the problem more clearly